# Can I delete my home folder to start fresh?

Tags: 12.10, home-directory

and if I can how?

I'm using Gnome Shell
If that matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. All you need to is backup any files you may need, then run the following:

`rm -rf ~/*`

If you still have files in your home folder, you can run Nautilus as root:

`gksu nautilus`

then navigate to your home folder, unhide all hidden files (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>) and select and delete them.

After this, log out and log back in, or restart your computer.